# Build in and build out of two images where one replaces the other in the same slide

Tags: keynote

I'm creating a Keynote presentation.

I have a slide with two overlapping images at the center of the slide. What I want to do is make one of the two disappear when the other appears. This should be done *in one slide*.

I've tried to add "build" effects or playing around with the orders, but I guess this may not be the right way to do it. I've also looked around on the web, but I've not found anything which really addresses my problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add build out to the first element and build in to the second.

   [image]
2. Set the build out to be with the build in.

   [image]

Preview:

[image]